# ul-element 5x the size of my browser?

Tags: jquery, html, css, html5-video

I'm trying to create a slideshow, in which the 'pages' of the slideshow all have different video backgrounds. Basically, [this](http://divergencepr.nl/team.html) is what I'd like to achieve. (But this video is the background of the whole webpage, so when the slideshow goes to the next page, it's the same video. Video div is the 'wrapper' or 'container' of the whole page, instead of just the slideshow page.)

But, when putting the video div inside the slideshow, [this](http://divergencepr.nl/team1.html) is what I get. For some reason the ul in which the list items are that contain the different pages, is 5x my browser width, while the ul's parent is 100%, so the browser width (in my case, around 1600px). The video does play, as seen in the 4th slide.
So, the ul is bigger than it's parent's width. For some reason it takes the whole ul (so all the list items together) as the stage for the video, which I do not want. I simply want the slider page, so, 100% of ONE list item, to be the video stage, so I can put different videos as each slider-page's background.

I hope what I'm trying to explain is clear.

I used the '[glide](http://jedrzejchalubek.com/glide/)' slider and [these](http://demosthenes.info/blog/777/Create-Fullscreen-HTML5-Page-Background-Video) [two](http://benkaminski.com/2013/05/26/responsive-html5-css3-video-background-in-div-no-javascript/) video tutorials.

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/style.css">
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style_demo1.css">
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fonts.css">

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="dist/jquery.glide.js"></script>


<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script>
document.createElement('video');
</script>
<![endif]-->
    </head>
<body id="intro">

    <header id="main">

    <a href="main.html"><h1 title="DIVERGENCE">DIVERGENCE</h1></a>

    <nav id="mainMenu">
        <a href="about.html">wie zijn we</a>
        <a href="work.html">wat doen we</a>
        <a href="team.html" class="mid-left">het team</a>
        <a href="cases.html" class="mid-right">cases</a>
        <a href="blog.html">blog</a>
        <a href="contact.html">contact</a>
    </nav>

    </header>

    <div id="social">
        <ul>
            <li class="socialMail"></li>
            <li class="socialFb"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="slider">
        <ul class="slider__wrapper">
            <li class="slider__item">
            <video autoplay loop poster="img/schrijven.jpg" id="bgvid">
                <source src="img/melisaOog.webmhd.webm" type="video/webm">
                <source src="img/melisaOog.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>

            <div id="video">

            <div class="box center" style="background:none">
                <section class="team">
                    <article>
                        <div class="teamInfo">
                        <h6>Melisa Dautovic</h6>
                        <p>Ide&euml;en enthousiast overbrengen, daar is Melisa sterk in.
            Ook blijft ze altijd positief, zelfs al gaan dingen wat minder,
            en weet ze dit over te brengen op de rest van het team.</p>
            <br/>
            <p><img src="img/mailico.png" class="mailico"> <a href="mailto:melisa@divergencepr.nl">melisa@divergencepr.nl</a></p>
                        </div>
                        <img src="img/fotoMelisa.png" class="teamFoto">
                    </article>
                </section>
            </div>
            </div> <!-- END OF VIDEO DIV -->
            </li>
            <li class="slider__item">
            <div class="box center" style="background:none">
                <section class="team">
                    <article >
                        <div class="teamInfo">
                        <h6>Nadine van Tuyl</h6>
                        <p>De creativeling van de groep die kleur aan het geheel geeft. Ontwerpen, om alles er mooi uit te laten zien, ide&euml;en bedenken 
die niet voor de hand liggen, als het maar creatief is.</p>
            <br/>
            <p><img src="img/mailico.png" class="mailico"> <a href="mailto:nadine@divergencepr.nl">nadine@divergencepr.nl</a></p>
                        </div>
                        <img src="img/fotoNadine.png" class="teamFoto">
                    </article>
                </section>
            </div>
            </li>
            <li class="slider__item">
            <div class="box center" style="background:none">
                <section class="team">
                    <article>
                        <div class="teamInfo">
                        <h6>Lisseth Visser</h6>
                        <p>Lisseth is onze rots in de branding. Op stressmomenten is zij diegene die heel kalm blijft en de rest van het team ook rustig houdt. Daarnaast is zij ook het aanspreekpunt van ons team.</p>
            <br/>
            <p><img src="img/mailico.png" class="mailico"> <a href="mailto:lisseth@divergencepr.nl">lisseth@divergencepr.nl</a></p>
                        </div>
                        <img src="img/fotoLisseth.png" class="teamFoto">
                    </article>
                </section>
            </div>
            </li>
            <li class="slider__item">
            <div class="box center" style="background:none">
                <section class="team">
                    <article>
                        <div class="teamInfo">
                        <h6>Name</h6>
                        <p>Text</p>
            <br/>
            <p><img src="img/mailico.png" class="mailico"> <a href="mailto:email">email</a></p>
                        </div>
                        <img src="img/photo.png" class="teamFoto">
                    </article>
                </section>
            </div>
            </li>
            <li class="slider__item">
            <div class="box center" style="background:none">
                <section class="team">
                    <article>
                        <div class="teamInfo">
                        <h6>Sammen Qureshi</h6>
                        <p>Stille wateren hebben diepe gronden. Hoewel Sammen in het team misschien wat stiller is, is ze wel ontzettend goed in woorden op papier zetten.</p>
            <br/>
            <p><img src="img/mailico.png" class="mailico"> <a href="mailto:sammen@divergencepr.nl">sammen@divergencepr.nl</a></p>
                        </div>
                        <img src="img/fotoSammen.png" class="teamFoto">
                    </article>
                </section>
            </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>


        <script>
            var glide = $('.slider').glide().data('api_glide');

            $(window).on('keyup', function (key) {
                if (key.keyCode === 13) {
                    glide.jump(3, console.log('Wooo!'));
                };
            });

            $('.slider__arrows-item').on('click', function() {
                console.log(glide.current());
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body, html {
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    background: #fff; 
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

body#intro{
    background:transparent;
}

video { 
    position: fixed;
    display:block;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -100;
    background-color:#fff;
    background:url(../img/schrijven.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
}

div#video{ 
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
    position:absolute;
}

div#verder{ 
    height:60px;
    width:321px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    color: white;
    margin: 0; padding: 5px;
    float: right;
    border:#ffffff solid 1px;
    border-radius:10px;

    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 25px;
    right: 25px;
}

div#verder a{
    text-decoration:none;
}

a:hover div#verder p{
    color:#808080;
}

a:hover div#verder{
    border:#808080 solid 1px;
}

div#verder p{
    font-family:'open_sanslight';
    font-size:20px;
    line-height:50px;
    color:#ffffff;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}


header#logo{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:100;
    max-width: 731px;
    width: 50%; 
    height:auto;
    overflow: auto; 
    margin: auto; 
    padding-top:5%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}

header#logo img{
    width:100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) { 
    div#verder{width:70%;} 
}
@media screen and (max-device-width: 800px) {
    html { background:url(../img/schrijven.jpg) #000 no-repeat center center fixed; }
    #bgvid { display: none; }
}

/* LOGO */

header#main {
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    z-index:100;
    width:100%;

/* background navigation menu */

/* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */

background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);

background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.9) 43%, rgba(255,255,255,0.8) 53%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */

background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(43%,rgba(255,255,255,0.9)), color-stop(53%,rgba(255,255,255,0.8)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,0))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */

background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.9) 43%,rgba(255,255,255,0.8) 53%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */

background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.9) 43%,rgba(255,255,255,0.8) 53%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */

background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.9) 43%,rgba(255,255,255,0.8) 53%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* IE10+ */

background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.9) 43%,rgba(255,255,255,0.8) 53%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* W3C */

filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#00ffffff',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */


}

/* Header has a height of 1.2em
the before and after set at 50% will together be 1.2em
but the nav beteen them will be 1.2em
so it's actually 3x 1.2em so 3.6em*/
header#main:before, header#main:after { 
    content: ''; 
    display: block; 
    height: 3.8em; 
    background: none; 
    width: 100%; 
}

h1{
    background-image:url(../img/logo_divergence_k.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;
    height: 142px;
    margin:0.5% 0; 
    padding:0;  
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 142px; 
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -71px;
}

/* MAIN MENU */ 

nav#mainMenu{ 
    width:100%; 
    text-align: center; 
    margin:0; 
    padding:0;  
    background-color:none; 
} 

nav#mainMenu a { 
    font-family:'open_sanslight';
    font-size:1em; 
    font-weight:100;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    color: #000; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    vertical-align: middle; 
} 

/* Make sure the menu is horizontally centered*/ 
nav#mainMenu li:first-child{ 
    margin-left:-20px; 
} 

/* create a spacer to get those dots */ 


nav#mainMenu a:after { 
    content: '\00B7'; 
    color:#a8e1d2; 
    display: inline-block; 
    width: 0; 
    padding: 0 2%; 
} 

nav#mainMenu a.mid-left:after { 
    width: 180px; 
    content: ''; 
} 

nav#mainMenu a.mid-right{
    margin-left:0px;
}

/* No spacer for the last child */ 

nav#mainMenu a:last-child:after { 
    display: none; 
}

nav#mainMenu a:nth-child(4):after, nav#mainMenu a:nth-child(5):after{
    width:55px;
}

nav#mainMenu a:hover{
    color:#a8e1d2;
}


/* Social */

div#social, div#social ul, div#social ul li{
    margin:0; padding:0;
}

div#social{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:5%;
    z-index:1000;
}

div#social ul{
    height:142px;
    display:table-row;
}

div#social ul li{
    width:10px; height:10px;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding:0 15px;
}

li.socialMail{
    background-image:url(../img/mail.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;
    background-size:contain;
}

li.socialFb{
    background-image:url(../img/fb.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;
    background-size:contain;
}

li.socialMail:hover{
    background-image:url(../img/mail_h.png);
}

li.socialFb:hover{
    background-image:url(../img/Fb_h.png);
}

/* Container */

div#container{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0; padding:0;
}

div.center{
    display:table;
}

body#index{
    background-image:url(../img/team.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:top;
    background-size:cover;
}

body#about{
    background-image:url(../img/verhaal.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:top;
    background-size:cover;
}

section#filler{
    height:90%;
}

section#kern{
    width:100%;
    display:table;

    font-family:'open_sanslight';
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:200;
    color:#363636;

    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}

section#kern.light{
    background: rgb(236, 236, 236);
    background: rgba(236, 236, 236, 0.9);
}

section#kern.dark{
    background: rgb(226, 226, 226);
    background: rgba(226, 226, 226, 0.9);
}

section#kern article{
    padding:0;
    margin:5% auto;
    width:70%;
}

section#kern img{
    width:23%;
    max-width:240px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin:0; padding: 1%;
}

section#kern div.text{
    width:70%;
    height:170px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin:0; padding: 4% 2%;
}

div#idle{
    width:100%; height:100%;
    display:table;
    margin:0; padding:0;
}

section#kern div.text p{
    width:100%;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin:0; padding: 0;
}

section#kern.light div.text p b{
    font-weight:bold;
    letter-spacing:7px;
    color:#ff8a78;
    font-size:30px;
}

section#kern.dark div.text p b{
    font-weight:bold;
    letter-spacing:7px;
    color:#77c9b3;
    font-size:30px;
}


/* scrollpijltje */

section#filler div#arrow{
    background-image:url(../img/arrow.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:contain; background-position:bottom;
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    width:50px; height:98%;
    margin:0 auto;
}


/* about */

section#about{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
}

section#about.visie{
    background-image:url(../img/visie.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:cover; background-position:bottom;
}

section#about.missie{
    background-image:url(../img/missie.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:cover; background-position:bottom;
}

section#about article{  
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left:25%;
    width: 75%;
    height:400px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 400px;
    margin: -15% 0 0 -25%;
}

section.team, section#contact{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0; padding:0;

    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

section.team article, section#contact article{
    display: inline-block;
    margin:0 auto; padding:0;
    font-family:'open_sansregular';
    font-size:20px;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    overflow:auto;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

section.team article div.teamInfo{
    width:42.5625%;
    margin:0; padding:0;
    padding-right:80px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}

section.team article div.teamFoto{
    margin:0; padding:0;
    width:22.625%;
    max-width:362px;
    margin-left:42.5625%;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}

section.team article h6, section#contact article h6{
    font-family:'wiegel_lateinmedium';
    font-size:100px;
    margin:0; padding:0;
}

img.mailico{
    position:relative;
    bottom:-6px;
    margin-right:6px;
}

div.teamInfo p a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#fff;
}

div.teamInfo p a:hover{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#a8e1d2;
}

div.teamInfo p a:active{
    color:#9c9591;
}


section#contact article form input, section#contact article form textarea{
    background:none;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    border-radius:10px;
    width:403px;
    height:43px;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:18px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    font-family:'open_sansitalic';
}

section#contact article form textarea{
    height:200px;
    padding:15px;
}

section#contact article form textarea:hover{
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.15);
}

section#contact article form input.button{
    font-family:'open_sansregular';
}

section#contact article form input:hover{
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.15);
}

section#contact article form input.button:active{
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}

a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#a8e1d2;
}

a:hover{
    color:#f9a497;
}

a:active{
    color:#fff;
}

.slider {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slider__wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  *zoom: 1;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.slider__item {
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  clear: none;
  position:relative;
}
.slider__arrows-item {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: -20px;
  padding: 20px;
}
.slider__arrows-item--right {
  bottom: 50%;
  right: 30px;
  background-image:url(../../img/arrowR.png);
  background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center; background-size:contain;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
}
.slider__arrows-item--left {
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 30px;
  background-image:url(../../img/arrowL.png);
  background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center; background-size:contain;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
}
.slider__nav {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
}
.slider__nav-item {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border-radius:12px;
  float: left;
  clear: none;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 5px;
  background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);}
.slider__nav-item--current {
  background: #a8e1d2;
}
.slider__nav-item:hover {
  background: #f9a497;
}

.box{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

* {
    margin:0; padding:0; border:0;
}
```

**Notes:** I probably have some html-errors or double id's or something like that. I still have to fix those things. And no, the site isn't responsive yet, it's on my to-do list.
So please, only respond on the problem at hand ;)

Comment: You probably also want the background video to cover the entire screen, but not to change its aspect-ratio. See http://fvsch.com/code/video-background/ for a nice solution to this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, what you want to achieve is to have one video per slide, i.e. the video of each slide should cover that slide, with the text/photo on top of the video.

***The solution***

The problem lies in the styling of the video tag, and not in the styling of the ul. Here are the changes I made to make it work:

```
video { 
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color:#fff;
    background:url(../img/schrijven.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
}
.slider__item {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    clear: none;
    position:relative;
}
div#video {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

***Explaination:***

- The video tag had position: fixed set. Position fixed is used to fix position something relative to the viewport, which is not what you want (since you want a different video for each slide). You can read more about position fixed [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Values). Width and height is automatically set to auto, so no need to specify them, and the z-index isn't needed at all, since you're absolute positioning your content on top of your video, which creates a separate stacking context (see [this article](http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/) for more info).
- The slide__item needs to have overflow set to hidden (strictly speaking, overflow-x hidden is enough) in order to prevent the video from spilling/overflowing from one slide over to the next.
- Last but not least, you need to tell the browser where you want to position the div#video element (it's somewhere off screen per default). Setting top and left will put it in the upper left corner, which together with the 100% width and height will achieve what you want.

***A note on the ul width and on performance***

The ul is supposed to be the width of all of the li's put together. What Glide.js does is to make a very long ul with all the li's positioned one next to the other. That way, the sliding is just a matter of moving the li in the center of the viewport. This has implications for the performance you'll see with the current solution you are aiming for, since you have 5 li's which, if I understood you correctly, will all be playing videos. Essentially, you'll be playing five videos at the same time, which might be heavy for the browser/computer to handle (especially if you're going to go responsive and target weaker "computers" like tablets and phones).

***Good luck!***

***Edit***
I'm not allowed to comment on the accepted answer yet, but it won't work if the screen is high enough (e.g. on a 1080p screen). Since the width will be forced to always occupy 100% and the height is set to auto, the ratio of the video will be maintained (a good thing). The problem lays in that if the width is the factor that determines the size of the video, the height might some times be set to low. My proposed solution will solve this problem by always making sure the width and height is minimum of 100% (just like in the original "solution"), so it will cover the whole page. Since width and height isn't set explicitly, they will both be set to auto and will thus maintain the proportions as well.

Comment: I just tried your approach, but when going to the 3rd page of the slide, my content just 'dissapears' and only the video is visible. Only the content of the first two slides is visible, and the third is visible when the page is 'sliding' but when the sliding's done, the content disappears. Do you have any tips to improve performance? Because at your solution the webpage (and I'm loading it locally) is very very slow, while the other approach loads pretty quickly.

Comment: This is the example from the first answer http://divergencepr.nl/team1.html, and this is the example from your answer http://divergencepr.nl/demo/team1.html. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Which browser are you using? Because your second link (/demo/team1.html) looks great here in both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: About performance - I don't think it matters which solution you go with css-wise, playing 5 videos at the same time is always going to be taxing for the computer. Maybe you can look into pausing the videos when they are not on screen, using the beforeTransition and afterTransition [options](https://github.com/jedrzejchalubek/Glide.js#options)?

Comment: Hmm I see. I use safari, maybe the issue is safari related then? At firefox it isn't playing anything?
By the way, is there any way to stop the video from starting until it's selected as 'page' for the slider? Maybe that will be better for the performance

Comment: What is it that you see in Safari? Could you describe the problem? We don't use anything fancy, so in theory it should work in Safari. Unfortunately, I don't have any Mac to test on. Firefox do play videos in ubuntu. Takes some time to load though, and it slows down the whole computer playing them.

Comment: Well, it takes a while to load because of the videos (you should hear my mac right now, lol) and when you're sliding from the 2nd page to the 3rd, at first you see the content. But when the sliding motion stops, the content disappears too. And the 4th and 5th slides are 'empty' except for the video.

Comment: Firefox (tested it on a ubuntu pc too) doesn't show any videos, while safari and chrome do.. But when I run the site locally, firefox does show video. Weird. Does this have to do with the performance? That firefox is somehow less equipped to play video?

Comment: Re-tested in both firefox and chrome, and all slide works and play video here at least. Which version of Firefox did you test on? Another comment, which won't help you solve the problem per sé - I would maybe try to take a step back and try to rethink the solution here. Try moving the video out of the slider and put it as a video background (should be a bunch of solutions available for that) and then use the glide API to switch the playing video based on which slide is shown. Even if you get the css together, we can see that performance will be an issue with my "solution".

Comment: Firefox 32.0.3, it said it's up to date. When I put the video outside of the slider it doesn't work either. So firefox is having issues with the video element, or so it seems. The weird thing is, the index page (divergencepr.nl/index.html) does work. That's another tutorial (you can see the two tutorials in my start post) but it seems kind of the same..  

And your solution is that I just use one video background, and with the help of jquery fill in the source (as that one is different at each page), right?

Comment: And I still don't understand why your solution doesn't work in safari, it seems like it puts the content behind the video (or just display:none) at the 3rd slide, but for no apparent reason. -edit- OK it just got weirder. When I use 'inspect element' in Safari on the slides that aren't displaying, the content appears.. When closing the content stays. But when the slider goes to the next page, the content isn't visible again and when using inspect element again it becomes visible. Weird!

Answer (score 2):

It takes the whole width because of position:fixed;

You can make it like this

```
video {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;    
    width: 100% !important;
    height: auto !important;
    z-index: -100;
    background-color: #fff;
    background: url(../img/schrijven.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that worked! Awesome :D. And it fixed my background-positioning too.. great :D.